# Why am I doing wrong when printing this string?

Tags: c, arrays, string, data-structures

I'm trying to set a char array into on of the structures but when I tried to print it out. I get a segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong?

```
typedef struct buckets_{
  char *key;
  data *next;
}buckets;

typedef struct hash_table_ {
  int (*hash_func)(char *);
  int (*comp_func)(void*, void*);
  buckets **buckets_array;
} hash_table, *Phash_table;

table_p -> buckets_array[0] = malloc(sizeof(buckets));
table_p -> buckets_array[1] = malloc(sizeof(buckets));

 char word2[5] = "Hieo";

table_p -> buckets_array[1] -> key = malloc(sizeof(word2));
table_p -> buckets_array[1] -> key = word2;
printf("%s",table_p -> buckets_array[i] -> key);  /*Getting segmitation falut here*/
```

Opp forgot to mention that I had a function to allocate the array. Assume that I the array allocated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I can see:

1. <strike>You did not allocate `buckets_array`.</strike>
2. You allocated memory for `key`, but then immediately leaked by by assigning `key = word2`. I guess you meant to use `strcpy` or `memcpy`.
3. You use a possibly uninitialized variable named `i`. I guess this is the problem.

Comment: Yes I didn't include some code. I did allocate an array before this. But your #2 statement might be why I'm getting the error.

Comment: @LearningC I suspect that 3 is more likely to be the cause.

Comment: Yes it was. Thank you. I forgot about that because I copied that line from another function. Thank you.

Comment: Can I do `strcpy(table_p -> buckets_array[1] -> key, word2);` ?

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `bucket_array`, so it is an invalid pointer.  You need to initialize it first:

```
table_p->buckets_array = malloc(number_of_elements * sizeof(buckets*));
// now that the top level pointer is initialize
// you can initialize each element that it points to.
```